# Disabling submit button until all inputs correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have succesfully managed to implement real time form validation for my registration page, it all works great except i want the form to disable the submit button up until the point all the inputs are correct and the user has checked the two check boxes (terms and conditions and privacy policy). I have tried giving it a go but i have never done it before, so not really sure where to start, i have asked a couple of people and apparently it is to do with the return false at the bottom of the javascript below. Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated. Thanks

HTML FORM

```
<div id="overlay">


<div id="modal_wrapper">
      <div id="modal_content">

        <form id="jform" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="modal_content_left">
            Register

            <ul>

                <li class="required" type="none">

                    <label>

                        <input type="text" class="reg_text tip" name="username" id="username" title="8 - 16 Characters" placeholder="Username*"/>

                    </label>

                    <label>
                         <br />
                        <input type="text" class="reg_text tip" name="email" id="email" title="Get Verified" placeholder="Email*"/>

                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <br />
                        <input type="password" class="reg_text tip" name="password" id="password" title="Min 8 Characters" placeholder="Password*"/>

                    </label>


                    <label>
                        <br />
                        <input type="password" class="reg_text tip" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" title="Min 8 Characters" placeholder="Verify Password*"/>
                    </label>
                </li>


            </ul>

            </div><!---end modal_content_left--->

            <div id="modal_content_right">

            <!--<li class="required double" type="none">-->


                <div id="payment_options">

                    <p>
                      <label><img src="images/index/images/paypal.png" width="78" height="38" alt="PayPal" />
                            <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="payment_selection" value="paypal" id="payment_selection_0" checked/>
                            </label>

                      <label><img src="images/index/images/alertpay.png" width="78" height="38" alt="Alertpay" />
                          <br />
                            <input type="radio" name="payment_selection" value="alertpay" id="payment_selection_1" />
                            </label>

                          <label><img src="images/index/images/check.png" width="78" height="38" alt="Check" /><br />
                            <input type="radio" name="payment_selection" value="check" id="payment_selection_2" />
                            </label>

          </p>
          <br /><br /><br /><br />
                    Account Type

                    <p>
                      <label><img src="images/index/images/demo.png" width="78" height="38" alt="Demo" />
                      <br />
                        <input type="radio" name="account_type" value="demo" class="demo_radio" id="account_type_0" />
                        </label>

                      <label><img src="images/index/images/real_account.png" width="78" height="38" alt="Real" /><br />
                        <input type="radio" name="account_type" value="real" id="account_type_1" checked/>
                      </label>

                    </p>
              </div><!---end payment_options---><br /><br /><br />

              <div id="final_reg">
              <div id="check_boxes">
              <p>
              <li class="required" type="none">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="agree_cons" value="terms" id="agree_cons_0" />
                  I agree to Terms</label>
                <br /><br />
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="agree_cons" value="privacy" id="agree_cons_1" />
                  I agree to Privacy Policy</label>
                  </li>

                <br />
              </p></div><!---end check_boxes--->
              <div id="register_submit">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" class="register_submit"
                       id="register_submit" alt="Register" />
              </div><!---end register_submit--->
            </div><!---end final_reg--->
         </div><!---end mofal_content_right--->

        </form>
      </div><!---end modal_content--->
      <div id="error_display"></div><!---end error_display--->
 </div><!---end modal_wrapper--->
```

Javascript CODE

```
$(document).ready(function () {
jFunc={
    mustMatch:  function(el,pt){
            if (pt.test(el.val()))
                el.removeClass('error').addClass('correct')
            else{
                jVal.errors = true;
                el.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').effect("shake", { times:3, distance:5 }, 60);
            }
        },
    mustEqual:  function (el,val){
            if (el.val()==val)
                el.removeClass('error').addClass('correct')
            else{
                jVal.errors = true;
                el.removeClass('correct').addClass('error').effect("shake", { times:3, distance:5 }, 60);
            }
        }
    }
jVal = {
    'username': function () {
        jFunc.mustMatch($('#username'),/^(?=.*[a-z].*)\w{8,}$/i);
    },
    'email': function () {
        jFunc.mustMatch($('#email'),/^.+@.+[.].{2,}$/i);
    },
    'password': function () {
        jFunc.mustMatch($('#password'),/^.{8,}$/i);
    },
    'cpassword': function () {
        jFunc.mustEqual($('#cpassword'),$('#password').val());
    },
};
$('#username').change(jVal.username);
$('#email').change(jVal.email);
$('#password').change(jVal.password);
$('#cpassword').change(jVal.cpassword);
$('#jform').submit(function(){
    $.each(jVal,function(i,v){
        $.isFunction(v) && v()
    })
    return false // fix this when the code works.
})
```

});

Comment: it would be only better if you make those code fragments in the same fragment, the ones which are split for unknown reasons

Comment: Hi, sorry i don't know why it all broke up, i have edited it now, thanks

Comment: It all broke up cause of the random outdents.  :P  Really, though, does the problem really require pasting every bit of the HTML?  It'd be helpful if you could whittle the HTML down to a minimal, but workable, example.

Comment: i was just annoyed by those breaks...fine, working on your solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to your existing event handlers, you could do something like

```
$('#username,#email,#password,#cpassword').change(function() {
    jVal.errors = false;
    $.each(jVal, function(i, validator) {
         if ($.isFunction(validator)) { validator(); }
    });
    $('#register_submit').prop('disabled', jVal.errors);
});
```

Note, though, you may want to have your submit handler check whether the submit button is disabled (and `return false` if it is, so the form doesn't submit) rather than doing the validation again itself.  That way all the validation happens from the same place.

(Of course, and just so it's said, none of this obviates the need for proper validation of the data on the server side.)

Comment: Ok great, but what might i add to enable/disable the submit button. Also i am also doing server side validation, i just want to give basic validation to the user that is in real time to stop the need for constantly running the php

Comment: great your code looks great, although it says there is an error on the 6th line ( $('#register_submit').prop('disabled', jVal.errors);) Which i think is the cause of none of the validation working at all, i have had a look but can't find what the error could be

Comment: There is a syntax error on line 152, which is the 6th line of the code above, it doesn't say anything else other than that, and i have found it stops validating the form altogether, i think this is from the error though, thanks for your help

Comment: Ahh.  Found it.  Forgot a `)` and a semicolon.  :)  BTW, it looks like `jFunc` could use a semicolon at the end of its definition as well.

Comment: Hi, ok there are no more errors shown, but it doesn't seem to work if for example i type into the username it goes green which shows it is correct, but as soon as i got to the email input, the email, password and password verify all go red to say there is an error, almost like it is running your script everytime you switch from one input to another where it should only run it when clicking the submit button. Any ideas, thanks so much for your help so far And also i just found that even if you do click the submit button, it still submits the form

Comment: The script *does* run every time you change an element, because that's the only way you're going to get the submit button enabled.  (If you only validate on submit, and you can't submit the form...)  If you don't want errors to display as such until you try to submit, then you need to separate the testing of the value from the setting of styles on the element.

Comment: The submit button starts out enabled.  Add `disabled="disabled"` to it to disable it.

Comment: Ok, i have done what you said and added the disable="disable", but it still doesn't submit when i enter everything correctly

Comment: That's because you have both a div and an input element with `id="register_submit"`.  IDs have to be unique, if you want stuff to work properly.  Change one or the other -- and if you choose to change the button's ID, of course, make the corresponding change to the code that enables it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i decided to just change the div id rather than the actual input id as it only requires to change the css, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. I have posted both the form and the javascript to pastebin. Here is the javascript validation - http://pastebin.com/9xRiJ3M7  AND here is the html form now updated - http://pastebin.com/DJ3mb9dj  Thanks for all your help

Comment: I just pasted your code, verbatim, into jsFiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/sAvtB/  Seems to work fine, other than all the blank fields being treated as errors.  The submit button enables just as it should.  (Do keep in mind, you told the form to `return false` when submitted, which prevents the default handler from running.  It won't submit til you tell it not to...or to `return false` only if there are errors.)

Comment: oh wow, i just tried it again, but changing it to return true, and it worked!, it disabled the button until all fields entered then went ahead and added the user correctly, thankyou so much. EDIT: i was just wondering for the sake of not opening another thread if i have to, do you happen to know how to set a different image for when its disabled to when it is available again?